# Enable Einstein Activity Metrics in scratch org

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I'm trying to set up our version control repo with the ability to push the entire repository to a new scratch org, however, I'm running into an issue pushing listViews to the org because we have einstein activity metrics enabled in production and the metrics fields are used in some of the listViews, resulting in the following error when trying to push the object (with listViews) to the scratch org.

```
Could not resolve list view column: LAST_ACTIVITY_DATETIME
```

How do you go about setting up scratch orgs with references to einstein activity metrics fields in the repository?